# If a large corporation gives you MS SQL Server Information, how do you plug it in?

Tags: sql-server

Here's the situation, a corporation needs a page on their website that searches through their inventory which contains tens of thousands of items. I was given this task however I have only worked with mySQL databases, and the database that this corporation uses is a Microsoft SQL Server that contains their inventory items.

Normally connecting to a database would be no sweat for me had I been given the same task to do this within a MySQL server and so I was handed the MS SQL Database details for connection and I've fired up a copy of visual studio ready to hack something up in visual basic to get this inventory search feature finished and out of the way.

This is where I'm at right now:

[image]

And so I'm going to add a connection to a remote database via this information that was provided to me and I'm not sure exactly where to plug it in:

[image]

This is almost EXACTLY what information I was given except I changed the details to phony names and numbers.

So my question is, how would I go about plugging in this information to this window?:

[image]

And if my first question is unanswerable than, was the information about the MS SQL Server "COMPANYover9000" insufficient to get me connected? By that I mean should I contact this corporations database manager for more details?

Comment: why don't you try it and see.  I hope that these values are fictitious.

Comment: He did say he gave phony names and numbers in the question.

Comment: Port 1433 is the default port for MS-SQL, so you can leave that out.  You shouldn't need the advanced properties either.  Just plug the IP address in the server name field, and add the credentials and click Test Connection to see if it works

Comment: In the "Add Connection" window, for "Server Name:" I entered "COMPANYover9000", and entered username and password into username and password, for database structure I entered "Quotes_SQL" then after clicking test connection, I get the error: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessable. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: Hi Dijkgraaf, thanks for commenting every little bit helps. I've tried just using the ip 66.66.66.666 for the server name and I've tried both COMPANYover9000 AND Usernet as usernames but still giving me the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: Can you `telnet 66.66.66.666 1433` from the command line ?  If it just says "Connecting to 66.66.66.666, there is no SQL Server listening or available at this address (maybe behing a firewall or something). If you get a blank screen, the connection occurs, there is something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do all of this and see if it works.
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/